# How to select rows which are not unique in columns of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a big data set but i can explain through a simple example. For example i have a matrix "x"

`x<- matrix(c(3,3,3,4,3,3,5,5,5), nrow=3, byrow=T)`

now i need second row in which "x" is not unique entries. First and third rows are equal in the sense of columns.

Regards and thanks in advance,

Iftikhar Ahmad

Answer (score 7):

You could also take advantage of the fact that equality means the standard deviation will always be 0. unfortunately we have to convert these 0s to logical either with a logical expression (below) or with `as.logical`.

```
x[apply(x, 1, sd) > 0, ]
```

**Update**

Did some benchmarking of @joran and my solutions. Mine lost :(

```
x <- matrix(sample(3:5,30000,T), ncol=3)    

system.time(x2 <- x[apply(x,1,sd) > 0, ])
user  system elapsed 
0.960   0.000   0.961

system.time(x2 <- x[apply(x,1,FUN=function(r){return(length(unique(r)))}) > 1,])
user  system elapsed 
0.470   0.000   0.465
```

But...

If we do a fully vectorised version with a similar theme, we can blow both out of the water

```
system.time(x2 <- x[rowSums(abs(x - rowMeans(x))) != 0, ])
user  system elapsed 
0.000   0.000   0.001
```

Comment: +1 Well done! Not to nitpick or anything, but doesn't your def of x create a matrix with only one column?

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
x[apply(x,1,FUN=function(r){return(length(unique(r)))}) > 1,]
```

that will select rows with more than one unique value in them.

Comment: +1 though `x[apply(x, 1, FUN=function(r){length(unique(r))} ) > 1, ]` would be slightly shorter and would avoid using `x` in two different senses (matrix and row) in the same line

Comment: @Henry Good catch on the double x; sloppy. The explicit 'return' in functions is just a habit of mine.